# How can I set an Android device audio source to a USB sound card?

Tags: android, audio

I am testing a sound recording App on a Motorola Moto G First Gen running Lollipop 5.1 ,In here everything works fine , I plug the USB sound card through the OTG cable and it automatically sets the audio source to the USB sound card input.

The problem comes while testing on the Samsung Galaxy Tab A device, Lollipop 5.0.2 ,it automatically sets the headphone output to the USB sound card, BUT the built-in microphone remains as the audio source.

I am using the AudioRecord class,and the AudioSource as DEFAULT